# Why is "kill" is not exiting a thread immediately?

Tags: windows, multithreading, perl, timeout, signals

I am trying to write a simple script that spawns a thread that performs a task that may timeout. (For the sake of writing a simple example for StackOverflow I replaced the actual process with a `sleep` command).

This program spawns a thread and then uses a `cond_timedwait` to monitor the thread and check if it has timed out. If a timeout occurs it calls the `kill` method on the thread with a "STOP" signal to notify the thread that it should exit.

```
use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use warnings;

my $var :shared;

my $thread = threads->create(sub {

    # Tell the thread how to handle the STOP signal
    local $SIG{'STOP'} = sub {
        print "Stop signal received\n";
        threads->exit();
    };

    # Perform a process that takes some time
    sleep 10;

    # Signal that the thread is complete
    lock($var); cond_signal($var);
});

# Current time + 1 second
my $wait_time = time() + 1;
my $timeout;

{
    # Wait for the thread to complete or until a timeout has occurred
    lock($var); $timeout = !cond_timedwait($var, $wait_time);
}

# Check if a timeout occurred
if ($timeout) {
    print "A timeout has occurred\n";

    # Signal the thread to stop
    $thread->kill('STOP')->join();
}
else {
    $thread->join();
}
```

This code runs successfully and prints the following output:

1 second passes...

```
A timeout has occurred
```

9 seconds pass...

```
Stop signal received
```

The problem is, even though a timeout is detected and the "STOP" signal is sent to the thread, the program still seems to be waiting the full 10 seconds before printing "Stop signal received" and exiting.

I tried changing it so it calls `detach` instead of `join` after killing the thread, but then the "Stop signal received" message is never printed which means the program is exiting before the thread cleanly exits. I want to make sure the thread is actually interrupted and exits, because in the real program I will want to kill and retry the process after the timeout has occurred and the process won't work if there is another instance already running on a detached thread.

How can I make it so the thread instantly prints the message and exits when it receives the "STOP" signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signals can only be sent to processes. As such, `$thread->kill('STOP')` can't possibly be sending an actual signal. As such, nothing interrupts `sleep`.

Between each statement, Perl checks if a "signal" came in. If it has, it handles it. So the "signal" is only handled once `sleep` completes.

If you had ten one second sleeps instead of one ten second sleep, the wait would be at most one second.

Comment: I confirmed that with a for loop and 10 one second sleeps it does catch the signal and exit the thread properly. Thank you for the very simple explanation.

Answer (score 2):

These "signals" aren't the actual OS signals, and there are operations they won't interrupt

> CAVEAT: The thread signalling capability provided by this module does not actually send signals via the OS. It emulates signals at the Perl-level such that signal handlers are called in the appropriate thread. For example, sending `$thr->kill('STOP')` does not actually suspend a thread (or the whole process), but does cause a `$SIG{'STOP'}` handler to be called in that thread (as illustrated above).
> ...
> Correspondingly, sending a signal to a thread does not disrupt the operation the thread is currently working on: The signal will be acted upon after the current operation has completed. For instance, if the thread is stuck on an I/O call, sending it a signal will not cause the I/O call to be interrupted such that the signal is acted up immediately.

The granularity of what the "*operation*" is isn't stated but `sleep` is clearly uninterruptable so the signal handler runs only after it completes. With a different job to interrupt

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use threads;

say "Start at ", scalar localtime, " (", time, ")";

my $thread = threads->create(sub {

    # Tell the thread how to handle the STOP signal
    $SIG{'STOP'} = sub {
        say "\tStop signal received. Exiting at ", time;
        threads->exit();
    };

    say "\tIn the thread ", threads->tid;

    # Perform a process that takes some time
    #sleep 10;
    do { sleep 1; say "\tnappin'... ($_ sec)" } for 1..10;
});

sleep 3;
$thread->kill('STOP')->join();  # works differently with detach()

say "Main thread done, exiting at ", time;
```

Output

```
Start at Thu Jul  7 11:11:27 2022 (1657217487)
        In the thread 1
        nappin'... (1 sec)
        nappin'... (2 sec)
        Stop signal received. Exiting at 1657217490
Main thread done, exiting at 1657217490
```

With `detach` instead of `join` it still stops that loop at the right time but I see no indication that a signal handler ran. (In my tests I have the signal handler also write a file and with `detach` it doesn't.) It all works the same for me with a shared variable etc, like in the question.

This `sleep` doesn't matter of course -- but it is all a warning to carefully test with actual jobs that the signal is aimed to stop.